# Which C++ Unit Test framework does not require I build my application as a library?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing

I would like to write some test code for a C++ class. Because the class is part of an application but not a part of library I would like to know which unit test framework does not require building project as a library in order to run unit test code?

I tried the WinUnit but it seems only can test a library.

Comment: I have a very very simple unit test library at github: https://github.com/AlexanderFabisch/CPP-Test . But it is only tested on Linux. I don't know if it is compatible to Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executables don't export symbols by default. You need to enable that with `-Wl,--export-dynamic` then link against the produced executable as though it was a library. This also means you need to do proper import/export on the classes you want to use etc.

Answer (score 2):

*Any* testing framework I know would allow that. It is an issue with the setting for your build environment, not the testing framework itself.

The easiest way to maintain it is to set up a library for your application code though.

I never used WinUnit, but I have used CppUnit and GoogleTest within VisualStudio projects where the code under test was not in a library, but the implementation files for the SUT were referenced (included) in the unit test project and it worked out.